# Audio Repeating More Than Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got two text boxes whose values are yes and no.and when i type yes in first text box, it beeps and the same should happen with remaining text box. The sound should play ONLY ONCE when i entered the correct value to the corresponding text boxes. In my case, the sound is repeating again and again...  dont know what might be the cause..

```
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<input type="text" id="question1"/> 
<audio src="beep.mp3" id="mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

function checkResults() {

    if ($('#question').val().toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
            document.getElementById("mp3").play();

    }

    if ($('#question1').val().toLowerCase() == 'no') {
        document.getElementById("mp3").play();
    }


}

$('input').blur(checkResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the window onblur event, you would need to check the event target to make sure its not the window first.

```
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<input type="text" id="question1"/> 
<audio src="beep.mp3" id="mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<script>
var isWindow = false;

function checkResults() {
    if (!isWindow) {
        if ($('#question').val().toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
            document.getElementById("mp3").play();
        }

        if ($('#question1').val().toLowerCase() == 'no') {
            document.getElementById("mp3").play();
        }
    }
}

$('input').blur(checkResults);

$(window).focus(function() {
    isWindow = false;
});

$(window).blur(function(e) {
    isWindow = true;
});
</script>
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safari browser

Comment: just for kicks, try it on another browser

Comment: I tried in chrome but here intersting thing happened. only one text box is responding i.e., playing.